# Using STATE as html ATTR in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, attributes, state, jsx

I am working in ReactJS, and have a URL of a photo stored in State. I want to use that photoURL to call up the image in my component render. But it when I use the normal `src={this.state.photoURL}` it throws an error.

Ideally, I would be able to use it as a background image in a container like this:

```
<div className='photo-cont' style='background-image:url({this.state.photoURL}); background-size:cover;'
```

I've tried this and as a normal img, with and without quotes around the curly braces, with and without the curly braces themselves.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  state: {
    photoURL: 'www.foobar.com/foo.jpg',
  }
  render () {
    return(
      <img src={this.state.photoURL}></img>
    )
  }
}
```

I keep getting the following error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'photoURL' of null'

Comment: Does it work if you change `state: {...` to `state = {...`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have a typo in your code. To initialize a class field (like `state` you should use `=`.

I added both an example of the `photoURL` as an image and as a background image of a div. Remember to set width/height/padding on the div to show the image:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    photoURL: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.photoURL}/>
        <div style={{
          width: '400px',
          height: '200px',
          backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.photoURL})`,
        }}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo extends Component {
 contructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   photoURL: 'www.foobar.com/foo.jpg',
  }
 }

  render () {
    return(
      <img src={this.state.photoURL}></img>
    )
  }
}
```

try to use contructor() to defined your state

Answer (score -1):

```
import logo from './logo.png';
class Foo extends Component {
  render () {
    return(
      <img src={logo}></img>
    )
  }
}
```

Check out their documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files

Comment: This assumes that the photo is a static asset. I don't think this is what OP is looking for. He specifically asked how to set the `src` property through state

Comment: Why would you even use state if it doesn't need to be? That how you teach new guys?

Comment: Since OP used state in his original code, I think it is reasonable to assume that he wants `photoURL` to be dynamic in some capacity.